# Laravel whereNotIn and where not working together together

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a function which involves the lines:

```
$products_to_ignore = $this->products()->get()->lists('id'); // returns [1,3,5]
$products = Product::
      whereNotIn('id', $products_to_ignore)
    ->where('stock_level', '>', 0)
    ->with('producer')
    ->get();
return $products;
```

And I have a DB table along the lines of the below

```
id    product_name    stock_level
1     eggs            5
2     cheese          0  
3     milk            1
4     cucumber        4   
5     pie             0
```

But the function above returns `[]`

If I just use

```
$products = Product::
      where('stock_level', '>', 0)
    ->with('producer')
    ->get();
return $products;
```

I'll get `[1,3,4]` and if I use:

```
$products_to_ignore = $this->products()->get()->lists('id'); // returns [1,3,5]
$products = Product::
      whereNotIn('id', $products_to_ignore)
    ->with('producer')
    ->get();
return $products;
```

I'll get `[2,4]`.

How come these two aren't playing nicely together? How do I grab the items which have a stock level greater than 0, which also aren't in the array `[1,3,5]`? For example, the first piece of code in this question should return product `[4]`, not in the array and also with a stock level > 0.

Comment: Make sure your data looks like in your example, because the code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `where` conditions adjacent to each other. Perhaps an `and` will reconcile them ;)

```
$products_to_ignore = $this->products()->get()->lists('id'); // returns [1,3,5]
$products = Product::where('stock_level', '>', 0,'AND')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $products_to_ignore)
    ->with('producer')
    ->get();
return $products;
```

As per API, \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php Line 773:

```
/**
 * Add a "where not in" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  mixed   $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function whereNotIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and')
{
    return $this->whereIn($column, $values, $boolean, true);
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Definitely... noob alert! Although that gives me the SQL: `select * from 'products' where AND 'id' not in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 16, 17, 18) 'stock_level' > 0` which I'm having trouble getting in the right order... am I being really dumb?

Comment: Reversed the order of the `where`s. Should be working properly now.

Comment: No need to pass `'and'` as it is the default value